# Adding %author% in custom post type URL structure?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, author

I'm trying to do some WordPress URL rewriting ...

Specifically I have custom post type that currently works like this:

`http://mydomain.com/videos/post-title/`

But I would like to have it located at:

`http://mydomain.com/videos/author-name/post-title/`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using Jhon's [Custom Post Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/)  plugin it should be easy 
using:

```
/%post_type%/%author%/%postname%/
```

Comment: This completely solved the issue I was having. Thanks.

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with your own code, without plugins.

To accept URLs of this format, it's enough if you set the rewrite slug when you register the post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse16427_init' );
function wpse16427_init()
{
    register_post_type( 'wpse16427', array(
        'label' => 'WPSE 16427',
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'video/%author%',
        ),
    ) );
}
```

This will also generate author archives at `video/[authorname]`.

To generate the new URLs, you need to replace the `%author%` part yourself, `get_post_permalink()` does not do this for you. So filter the output and replace it yourself:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse16427_post_type_link', 10, 4 );
function wpse16427_post_type_link( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample )
{
    if ( 'wpse16427' == $post->post_type ) {
        $authordata = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
        $post_link = str_replace( '%author%', $author, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: It's important to note here that the `10,4` part of `add_filter` is required to make this work. The precedence can be anything, but you have to specify at least `2` in the spot where the arguments list is defined, or you will not have access to `$post`

Answer (score 0):

goto the permalinks section on the settings in the admin panel, set a `custom  structure` like so:

```
/%category%/%author%/%postname%/
```

**NOTE**

this assumes `videos` is a category

[Check here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) for more options.

Comment: Videos is not a category. It's a custom post type.

Comment: I think that you can just drop the /%category% bit, and Wordpress will stick the slug for your post type there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use the following structure if you installed wordpress in a subdirectory (videos)

/%author%/%postname%/