# Allow duplicate permalinks slugs for custom posts by different authors

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

If two vendors has the same product then when the second vendor publish the product in to the store, 2 is appended to the permalink since the same product from the first vendor already exist

Is there any solution to remove the numeric from the permalink?
Ideally, the two permalinks should look like this:

http://example.com/author-1/post-title/

http://example.com/author-2/post-title/

But when I publish the second post, then its slug is changed to post-title-2, which makes the resulting URL 
http://example.com/author-2/post-title-2/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding %author% in custom post type URL structure?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/adding-author-in-custom-post-type-url-structure)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hack something, but in wordpress the slug is a unique identifier of a post. Trying to mess around it might impact other functionality in an unpredictable way depending on your themes and plugins.

The right solution to having multi authors which can not or do not want to synchronize between them is to use a multisite.

An easier solution is to force them to use a more explicit slugs (I find it hard to believe that they sell the exact same product).

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to add an id/sku of the product to the slug. 
If even the id/sku is the same than and an ID for the vendor.